# Unable to retrieve SHA1 Checksum of a file residing on S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, checksum, sha

So I am trying to fetch the SHA1 hash of a file that resides on AWS S3 bucket. According to their [blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-additional-checksum-algorithms-for-amazon-s3/) post, they activated it in February 2022. This is my code:

```bash
aws s3api get-object-attributes \
          --bucket <bucketName> \
          --key <fileName> \
          --object-attributes "Checksum"
```

But when I try to execute it I only get the modification date. If I exchange `Checksum` with `ETag` it correctly displays the `ETag` of the file.

Here I am following their [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/get-object-attributes.html) and according to my understanding passing `Checksum` should return me the CRC and SHA hashes of the file.

Comment: Did you turn on Additional Checksums as mentioned in the blog post?

Comment: yes, I have tried to turn the Checksum as it was mentioned in the blogpost and I ended up with a different SHA1sum. I am calculating it with `sha1sum` and getting  `4d2d48def0b6d18ebd9e34a4db128bea63e95184` while the one returned by AWS is `TS1I3vC20Y69njSk2xKL6mPpUYQ=` which I believe is encoded SHA1sum. Initially thought it is Base64, but it isn't.

Comment: Those are the [same value](https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/#recipe=From_Base64('A-Za-z0-9%2B/%3D',true,false)To_Hex('None',0)&input=VFMxSTN2QzIwWTY5bmpTazJ4S0w2bVBwVVlRPQ), one is encoded using hex encoding, the other using base64.